# Spring Cyclic dependency with RHLC Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

Does someone maybe know whats the problem that i always get this cyclic dependency when trying to configure my RHLC with the ApiCompatibilityMode?

```
package product.config;

import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.config.AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration;


@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private RestHighLevelClient client;

  @Override
  public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
      RestHighLevelClientBuilder clientBuilder = new RestHighLevelClientBuilder(client.getLowLevelClient())
              .setApiCompatibilityMode(true);

      return clientBuilder.build();
  }
}


Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

       testApplication (field private org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations product.TestApplication.elasticsearchOperations)
    ┌─────┐
    |  elasticSearchConfig (field private org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient product.config.ElasticSearchConfig.client)
    └─────┘
```